# The message for class "Exception" causes PHP Fatal Error

Tags: php, exception

After execute this simple code:

```
$message = 'some text '.inet_pton('119.252.33.171');
throw new \Exception($message);
```

PHP returns Fatal Error

```
Fatal error</b>: in ...
```

This code is expected to return

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: ..
```

But this is not happening. With this message, the error occurs in the class "Exception"!

[Code example 1 from sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec62de5dc918502b13628bdbb240e77f07edb87a) (comment and uncomment 2 lines of code 3-4 and 6-7)

[Code example 2 from sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0010e95a4bec4f6a4521ad58af90db256db6224b)

This behavior is noticed when converting many other IPs.
At the moment I solved the problem with the following line before "throw new":

```
$message = preg_replace( '/[^[:print:]\r\n]/', '_', $message);
```

How to properly escape characters in message for Exception or it is PHP bug?

My PHP version is 7.2

Comment: Your title and your question don't match and confusing, when you throw an Exception, of cause it will cause a `Fatal error`. Did you catch the Exception?

Comment: No, because the error message `'some text '.inet_pton('119.252.33.171');` itself causes an error in the Exception class. Run my example on your hosting and look at the result.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error with just the `inet_pton` call. Are you sure that's the cause of the exception?

Comment: @Miron Are you sure about the fatal error? Doesn't happen on my 7.2.11 with display_errors set and E_ALL. What's the exact message for the fatal error?

Comment: `<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:   in <b>...</b> on line <b>92</b><br />`

Comment: I can't reproduce that either: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2970fae730706bfd48b6ad558e326e0abef31149

Comment: If delete '.inet_pton('119.252.33.171')' from `$message` all is ok, i received Uncaught Exception: `Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: some text in ..:92 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in ... on line 92`

Comment: Look as in my example and you will be surprised (comment and uncomment 2 lines of code) http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2137e963b7ef7e2c6e6b914a4de511cb967f2724

Answer (score 1):

That would be because `inet_pton()` is not meant to ouput strings, but bytes in network order (I don't remember if it's little endian or big endian).

Exception messages are not meant to include bytes, but printable characters. You can, however, put pure bytes into strings. These are then decoded to (probably) UTF-8 or other encoding to display readable text.

The following code

```
$message = inet_pton('119.252.33.171');
var_dump($message);
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($message); $i++)
{
   echo ord($message[$i]) . "\n";
}
```

Produces

```
string(4) "w�!�"
119
252
33
171
```

Compare these two lines

```
throw new \Exception(chr(33)); // Displays stacktrace
throw new \Exception(chr(252)); // Fails to output
```

My guess would be that an error occurs while PHP is trying to format the string as UTF-8 to print the exception message to stdout, but invalid UTF-8 string is passed in and the write/decoding fails.

Either way, seems like a bug in PHP.

Comment: So this is the PHP error - it is true. Only in your example is better to use mb_ord().

Answer (score 0):

You are using `inet_pton()` incorrectly because this is what it does:

```
inet_pton — Converts a human readable IP address to its packed in_addr representation
```

You should append the address to the string without calling `inet_pton()`.

Now, about the error.

The error doesn't occur in all my PHP setups, from 5.5.12 to 7.2.8.
This is the error message I got from PHP 5.5.12:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'some text wü!«' in C:\wamp\www\so\54584039.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\so\54584039.php on line 5
```

I got the same "Uncaught exception" error from other versions, confirmed by https://3v4l.org/Klpep.

This means that the error must be caused by a post-processing of the Exception message that occurs in your PHP setup
but does not occur in 3v4l.org's setup and mine.

It occurred to me that a possible culprit is the `html_errors` configuration option.
I set it to `On` to find out what's going to happen and sure enough, I got your error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:   in <b>C:\wamp\www\so\54584039.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
```

Thus, the solution is to set your `html_errors` to `Off`.

I highly recommend that you set it to `Off` always,
because if you're working on a JSON output (or other formats) the HTML formatting is useless and it also makes the error message harder to read.